# How do I start up an MFC application from scratch?

Tags: c++, mfc

In other words from a blank win32 project (no wizard).

This is where I am at:

Preprocessor Definitions: WIN32

Linker->System->Subsystem = Console

```
int _tmain()
{
    int nRetCode = 0;

    // initialize MFC and print and error on failure
    if (!AfxWinInit(::GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL, ::GetCommandLine(), 0))
    {
        // TODO: change error code to suit your needs
        _tprintf(_T("Fatal Error: MFC initialization failed\n"));
        return nRetCode = 1;
    }

    MyWinApp* app = new MyWinApp();

    app->InitApplication();
    app->InitInstance();

    app->Run();

    AfxWinTerm();

    return 0;
}


class MyWinApp: public CWinApp
{
public:
    BOOL InitInstance();

    int Run();
};


BOOL MyWinApp::InitInstance()
{
    return TRUE;
}

int MyWinApp::Run()
{
    return CWinThread::Run();
}
```

Skipping over the CWinApp::Run() because it looks for a main window.

In CWinThread::Run() however, the ASSERT_VALID fails. At the top of quickwatch for this it says MyWinApp is invalid.

Do I need to create MyWinApp in another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably failing because you're creating the `CWinApp` *after* you're calling `AfxWinInit`. In a regular MFC app, the `CWinApp` is a global variable, which is constructed before `main`. This way, when MFC is initialized, it has a valid global `CWinApp` in place. Try:

```
MyWinApp* app = new MyWinApp();   // ^moved up^

// initialize MFC and print and error on failure
if (!AfxWinInit(::GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL, ::GetCommandLine(), 0))
{
    // TODO: change error code to suit your needs
    _tprintf(_T("Fatal Error: MFC initialization failed\n"));
    return nRetCode = 1;
}
```

Comment: That works. Apparently there is some magical stuff in CWinApp that makes this work?

Comment: @Fredrick, dunno if that's magical stuff... `CWinApp`'s constructor registers itself as, well, the module's `CWinApp`. There's a ton of wiring in MFC, easiest way is usually to just use the wizard (if that's possible).

Comment: There is no need to allocate `app` on heap.

Comment: I don't use Microsoft tools very much, is "and print and error" Microsoft-specific speech for something?

Comment: @LimitedAtonement guess we all missed that :). "We" here being the folks who wrote [the documentation on MS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w04bs753.aspx) as well as the 10k copy+pastes found by Google when looking for this exact phrase...

Comment: @eran I noticed it when I created a new c++ project using Microsoft Visual Studio. I'm guessing your documentation came from the code (from Microsoft Visual Studio).