# Compiling an MFC GUI application as a DLL in VS2012

Tags: c++, dll, mfc

Is it possible to compile an MFC GUI EXE project into a DLL and then execute this DLL application from another application?

My progress so far is:

- I changed "Configuration properties | General | Configuration type" to DLL
- I added an exported function creating and running the application using this code:

  ```
  theApp.m_hInstance = pModuleState->m_hCurrentInstanceHandle;
  theApp.InitInstance();
  theApp.Run();
  ```
- I added code to DLLMain to initialize module state:

  ```
  if (dwReason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH)
  {
      AFX_MODULE_STATE* pModuleState = AfxGetModuleState();
      pModuleState->m_hCurrentInstanceHandle = hInstance;
      pModuleState->m_hCurrentResourceHandle = hInstance;
  ```
- I created a console application that loads the DLL and calls the function creating and running the DLL application.

Yet, I'm still getting various debug assertions as, for example, AfxGetThread returns NULL, etc. And the application fails to run.

Can someone tell me if my idea of making DLL from EXE is realistic?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you call AfxWinInit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124307/how-do-i-start-up-an-mfc-application-from-scratch

Comment: Why do you want to do such a thing? The Major Problem is how do you want to implement the message Loop. Do you want just a simple call like DoMdal to execute the application. What sense does it make to have a EXE in a DLL?