# How to initialize a windowed MFC application from main() in C++/Windows

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

I'm using MFC to create a windowed Windows application in C++ (using Windows 10/VS2017). This works fine if I use the default initialization behavior where I create an instance of my class derived from CWinApp in main.cpp:

```
// main.cpp
// Define a window class derived from CFrameWnd
class MyCustomWindow : public CFrameWnd {
  public:
    MyCustomWindow() {
        Create(NULL, _T("Hello World!"), WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, rectDefault); 
    }
};

// Define an application class derived from CWinApp
class MyCustomApp : public CWinApp {
  public:
    virtual BOOL InitInstance() {
        m_pMainWnd = new MyCustomWindow();
        m_pMainWnd->ShowWindow(m_nCmdShow);
        m_pMainWnd->UpdateWindow();
        return TRUE;
    }
};

MyCustomApp app;  // HelloApp's constructor initializes and runs the app
```

However, I'd love to be able to use the standard main() entry point so I can more-easily make a cross-platform wrapper class to launch applications. I'm trying to do that using the following code (instead of initializing a MyCustomApp instance outside of any function/class in main.cpp as above, using code suggested here: [How do I start up an MFC application from scratch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124307/how-do-i-start-up-an-mfc-application-from-scratch));

```
// same class definitions as above ...
// removed line: MyCustomApp app;

#ifdef _MSC_VER
#pragma comment(linker, "/subsystem:windows /ENTRY:mainCRTStartup")
#endif

int main(const char* argv, int argc)
{
    int nRetCode = 0;

    MyCustomApp app;

    // initialize MFC
    if (!AfxWinInit(GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL, GetCommandLine(), 0))
        return nRetCode = 1;

    app.InitApplication();
    app.InitInstance();
    app.Run();
    AfxWinTerm();
    
    return 0;
}
```

This compiles and runs, but my window is never shown. Any ideas how to get it to actually show the app window?

Comment: I don't do MFC but this might help you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwinapp-class?view=msvc-170#m_ncmdshow

Comment: *"I'd love to be able to use the standard main() entry point so I can more-easily make a cross-platform wrapper class to launch applications."* - Can you explain what the goal is here, and why the name of the entry point matters?

Comment: Regardless, the final parameter to `AfxWinInit` is what becomes the value stored in `m_nCmdShow`. The code is passing 0 (aka `SW_HIDE`), so that could explain why the window doesn't show. Since the whole `m_nCmdShow` business is [handled by the system](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-showwindow) already, you can unconditionally pass `SW_SHOWNORMAL` in the first call to `ShowWindow` and get the same behavior as if you had gone through all the trouble of evaluating the initial show state passed down (or not) by the system.

Comment: Passing SW_SHOWNORMAL as the last argument to AfxWinit worked, thankyou!!